# Elevators and Multifloor Navigation

Tags: navigation, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the JSK/TUM code to [use an elevator and navigate on multiple floors](http://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2011/10/04/jsk-and-tum-teach-pr2-fetch-you-sandwich-subway) available anywhere?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12839/elevators-and-multifloor-navigation/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a developer of navigation system with taking elevators in JSK.

The codes are in jsk-ros-pkg (http://jsk-ros-pkg.svn.sourceforge.net/),
and the main package is elevator_move_base_pr2.
We are using Euslisp programming language for describing procedure of
taking elevator and geometrical elevator call button models.

And navigating between multiple maps, we have to change grid map in move_base and amcl.
These scripts are in jsk_maps package.

---

Originally posted by [manabu](https://answers.ros.org/users/64/manabu/) with karma: 46 on 2012-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-02-03**:
Thank you! In case anyone else is looking, the package multi_map_server is under the jsk_ros_patch folder.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-08-02**:
Thanks to sourceforge weirdness, one needs to look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsk-ros-pkg/ and then the tab "Code", not the tab "Files".

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-12-02**:
Looks like the jsk code repo has moved to [github](https://github.com/jsk-ros-pkg/jsk_demos/tree/master/elevator_move_base_pr2).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although it's not the JSK/TUM code, Eitan Marder-Eppstein, Kurt Konolige, and Bhaskara Marthi cover this topic in their [paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.willowgarage.com%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Ficra-top-nav.pdf&ei=hXgpT8bjLILw0gGB9cioAg&usg=AFQjCNEFLxiLsq-G9hmGIQm8W7v49Is9Qg). There is an implementation of this [here](http://ros.org/wiki/topological_navigation).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-02-01**:
That paper seems to only mention the possibility of using it for multi-floor navigation, specifically for parking garages, where you have ramps that go from floor to floor.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not exactly sure which code you mean, but my colleague [Lars Kunze](http://ias.cs.tum.edu/people/kunze) (TUM) recently did an internship at JSK and was involved in the Subway-Sandwich-Demo that involved an elevator. I´m pretty sure, he can help you...

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-02-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1